# How to hide surface Preview in Camera API

Tags: android, camera

I am writing a simple app where I am broadcasting my webcam. 
Android Camera API requires startPreview on a view which has to be visible all times.

In my app, the user may be doing n things so the activity where the webcam is visible (Preview) cannot be on top at all times.

Android camera stops when activity goes below another one.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Records camera video in background service:

https://github.com/munnadroid/AndroidBackgroundVideoRecording

some of my other android development notes:

http://dave.thehorners.com/tech-talk/programming/459-android-programming